# Is it possible to invoke a C# method from Java script from WPF Web browser control?

Tags: javascript, html, wpf, dom-events, wpf-controls

I'm using a Tab control in WPF and the Tab control contains a WebBrowser control in first tab. I have some scripts and HTML content for the Webbrowser control and this works fine. Also I'm able to invoke the script method written inside the HTML content, but I need the vice versa as need to invoke a C# method from Javascript method.

Is it possible?

Comment: is the C# method exposed as webmethod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an object which is accessible to be called directly from your JavaScript. Check out the property [ObjectForScripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx) on the [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control for more information.

Also, here is another post which outlines it even better: [Hosting and interacting with a webpage inside a WPF App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470222/hosting-and-interacting-with-a-webpage-inside-a-wpf-app)